# Issues with equi-join query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with this query  :

```
select 
    distinct count(avancementtotal1.id_Module) as 'number module not realised'
    ,count(avancementtotal2.id_module) as 'number module  realised'
    ,Groupe.name_Groupe,Groupe.Year 
From 
    AvancementTotal avancementtotal1
join 
    Module on Module.id_Module = avancementtotal1.id_Module 
join 
    Affilate on Module.id_Affilate = Affilate.id_Affilate
join 
    Groupe on Groupe.id_Groupe = avancementtotal1.id_Groupe
join 
    AvancementTotal avancementtotal2 on avancementtotal1.id = avancementtotal2.id
where 
    avancementtotal2.State_efm = 'EFM Realised'
    and avancementtotal1.State_efm = 'EFM Not REALISEd'
    and avancementtotal1.id <> avancementtotal2.id
Group by 
    Groupe.id_Groupe, Groupe.name_Groupe, Groupe.Year, Affilate.name_Affilate
```

It returns null and I want to know why.

I want to have the number of module not realised and in the same moment have the module who have state of EFM REALISEd

here the structure :
[image]

Comment: Your join condition states `avancementtotal1.id = avancementtotal2.id`, and then in your where clause you state `avancementtotal1.id <> avancementtotal2.id` - these two can't ever co-exist. Can you share your table 's structure?

Comment: I can't send image can you give me your email ? for send it

Comment: I can send image here ? with my reputation ?

Comment: just post the DDL of the table

Comment: I have post the full image

Comment: I try to delete this line avancementtotal1.id <> avancementtotal2.id but is still empty

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to display from your query? I noticed the Group By Clause is grouping by quite a few fields that are not needed.

Comment: because the number of modules depends on the fields  and  groups you see if i don't care of field i will have many result on the same field so i groupe also with fields

Comment: and it work very good with only avancementtotal1 for exemple when i make the second avancementtotal2  it return empty table

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do this as a conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when avt.State_efm = 'EFM Not REALISEd' then 1 else 0 end) as NumNotRealized,
       sum(case when avt.State_efm = 'EFM Realised' then 1 else 0 end) as NumRealized,
       g.name_Groupe, g."Year"
From AvancementTotal avt join 
     Module m
     on m.id_Module = avt.id_Module join 
     Affilate a
     on m.id_Affilate = a.id_Affilate join 
     Groupe g
     on g.id_Groupe = avt.id_Groupe
Group by g.id_Groupe, g.name_Groupe, g."Year", a.name_Affilate;
```

Notice that this only joins to the `AvancementTotal` table once and replaces the counts in the `select` with conditional `sum()`s.

I also made the following changes:

- Added table aliases to make the query more readable
- Removed the single quotes around identifiers.  Although allowed, you should only use single quotes for string and date constants
- Added double quotes around `year` because it is a reserved word

I also suspect that `a.name_Affilate` should either be in the `select` clause or not in the `group by` clause.

Comment: That what i want thank you very mush (y) (y) its very helpfull i can't vote you :(